# Repeating Images in HTML Preview

Tags: image, jasper-reports, subreport

I have created a report in *iReport-5.5.0 (JasperReports)* with a pair of images that displays properly in it's internal preview, pdf, and word.  When I generate html from the report, I get hundreds of extra occurrences of my images in various sizes all throughout the resulting document.  The images in question are contained (one each) in *SubReports* in my form, but all of the *SubReport* content is static.  Furthermore, the *SubReports* are contained in *Page Header* and *Page Footer* bands, and the *SubReports* themselves also only contain either a *Page Header* or *Page Footer* band.

Why is the html not displaying the report correctly?  Where are these extra images coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression class for my images from when they were dragged out were set to 'java.lang.String'.  When I changed them to 'java.awt.image', the repeating stopped.  It looks like they may have reverted back, but the repeating didn't come back, so I'm not worrying about it.

Comment: I also have this problem exactly.  I tried your solution, but image stopped showing.  To use java.awt.image, is there a change to the expression?  Mine has the file path.